# How to download gradle dependencies from local jar

Tags: maven, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-eclipse

I have a local jar which I have included in my build.gradle. This jar refers to some dependent jars which are listed as part of jar's META-INF/maven/{package}/pom.xml

When I add this jar as part of my gradle compile dependencies it doesn't download the dependent jars listed in the pom.xml

How can I download the dependent jars for the local jar in my project?

Comment: Please add relevant sections of your build file: `repositories`, `dependencies` and any other where that jar plays a role. Without that information, hard to provide a specific answer.